# Partitioning Disk: Maximum Partitions Reached in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I was installing Windows 7 using the CD. I have 3 partitions already, and when creating a new partition using the DVD, it says "You cannot create a new volume in this unallocated space because the disk already contains maximum number of partitions." How can I create more partitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an extended partition, then you can create logical partitions. I don't know if Windows 7 will install on a logical partition though

**Explanation:** (from [Wikipedia - Disk Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types))

> This section describes the master boot record (MBR) partitioning scheme, as used in DOS, Microsoft Windows and Linux among others on PC
>   compatible computer systems. For examples of partitioning schemes used
>   in other operating systems, see the general article on partition
>   tables.
>
> The total data storage space of a PC hard disk can be divided into at most four primary partitions, or alternatively three primary
>   partitions and an extended partition. These partitions are described
>   by 16-byte entries that constitute the Partition Table, located in the
>   master boot record.
>
> The partition type is identified by a 1-byte code found in its partition table entry. Some of these codes (such as 0x05 and 0x0F) may
>   be used to indicate the presence of an extended partition. Most are
>   used by an operating system's bootloader (that examines partition
>   tables) to decide if a partition contains a file system that can be
>   used to mount / access for reading or writing data.
>
> **Primary partition**
>
> A primary partition contains one file system. In DOS and earlier versions of Microsoft Windows systems, the system partition was
>   required to be the first partition. More recent Windows operating
>   systems (Win7, XP, etc.) can be located on any partition, but the boot
>   files (bootmgr, ntldr, etc.) must be on a primary partition. However,
>   other factors, such as a PC's BIOS (see Boot sequence on standard PC)
>   may also impart specific requirements as to which partition must
>   contain the primary OS.
>
> The partition type code for a primary partition can either correspond to a file system contained within (e.g. 0x07 means either
>   an NTFS or an OS/2 HPFS file system) or indicate that the partition
>   has a special use (e.g. code 0x82 usually indicates a Linux swap
>   partition). The FAT16 and FAT32 file systems have made use of a number
>   of partition type codes due to the limits of various DOS and Windows
>   OS versions. Though a Linux operating system may recognize a number of
>   different file systems (ext4, ext3, ext2, ReiserFS, etc.), they have
>   all consistently used the same partition type code: 0x83 (Linux native
>   file system).
>
> **Extended partition**
>
> A hard disk may contain only one extended partition; the extended partition can be subdivided into multiple logical partitions. In
>   DOS/Windows systems, each logical partition may then be assigned an
>   additional drive letter.

Basically, you can have 4 "real" partitions on a disk; to get more, you make up to 3 Primary partitions, then 1 "extended" partition that has multiple "logical" partitions inside of it. The extended partition does NOT get a drive letter, but the logical partitions inside of it would get letters if assigned

Comment: i want to install ubuntu on that extra 4 th partition can i ?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Yup

Comment: how to create that extra partition ? via disk management utility provided in windows 7 ? if yes then how ? please give detailed info because i'm afraid to lost data on other drives . thanks

Comment: ok done it. i've converted it to dynamic . thanks for your suggestion .

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Not a problem. I'm going to do a writeup to expand on the answer as to why